# shortcode for a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have these code to create my button short code:

```
add_shortcode( 'modal', 'modal_shortcodes' );
function modal_shortcodes( $atts ) {

    $attr = shortcode_atts(array(
        'btn_name' => 'default button name',
    ), $atts);

    $content =  '<button>'. esc_attr($attr['btn_name']) . '</button>'; 
    return $content;
}
```

and I have these codes to create custom post type:

```
function custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type('multi-step-form', array(
    'supports' => array('title'),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Multi-Step Forms',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Multi-Step Form',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Multi-Step Form',
      'all_items' => 'All Multi-Step Forms',
      'singular_name' => 'Multi-Step Form'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-universal-access-alt',

  ));               
}
```

I want to know how can I do the following:

1. The custom post type I created 'multi-step-form' <-- every time I add a  new post, it will generate a short code (for each post).

Example: I will add a post title 'button1"

then it will dynamically create a short code like `<button class"button1"></button>`

2. then if I create another post, it will create again another short code (depends on the title) to create a button like `<button class="button2"></button>`

Any ideas what should I research for my to achieve those?

Please see this screenshot for example: [image]

Comment: Point 2 of your question is confusing. What do you mean by the class? Do you mean the button text as before? Do you want to create custom posts templates that automatically have a button on the front end with a text = title of the post?

Comment: @omukiguy  I added a screenshot and edited the #2

Answer (score 0):

found this answer from [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/WPUGPH/permalink/632863767044931/).

1. create a function, that loops thru all your custom post.
2. in that same function, register a shortcode for each post. maybe you can use the slug as short code name.
3. hook this function to actions like "init". but consider that this make all you post based shortcodes loaded in every time a page is requested.